# Change images in pictureboxes while loading long running process -vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

In my main form, when I click submit button, long running process (5 methods) will be executed. At that time, I just want to show individual form with 5 cross images. At the time of completion of methods one by one, I want to change cross image to tick image. 
I tried the code as follows:

> 

```
 Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
 > 
    Try
        If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Try
        Retrieve()         
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub Retrieve()
    Try
        RetrieveForm.Show()
        Dim thrd1 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf RetrieveClient))
        Dim thrd2 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf RetrieveProject))
        Dim thrd3 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf RetrieveModule))
        Dim thrd4 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf RetrievePerson))
        Dim thrd5 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf RetrieveStatus))
        Dim thrd6 As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf RetrievePriority))
        thrd1.Start()
        tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbClient)
        thrd2.Start()
        tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbProject)
        thrd3.Start()
        tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbModule)
        thrd4.Start()
        tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbUsers)
        thrd5.Start()
        tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbStatus)
        thrd6.Start()
        tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbPriority)
        Application.DoEvents()
        MessageBox.Show("Retrieved")
        RetrieveForm.Close()
        InitialLoad()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub tickimage(ByVal pbId As PictureBox)
    Try
        pbId.InitialImage = Nothing
        Dim img As Image = Resources.tick1
        pbId.Image = img
        pbId.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub`
```

In this code, when I click the button, at the very first time itself, all the images are tick. I want to change image from cross to tick one by one at the end of each methods.
I don't know what is wrong with my code.. Please correct me if anyone find any mistakes in it.

Comment: call tickimage method after complete the threading method. That means after finished the thread method execution then invoke the tickimage method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out ...

```
Private R As New Random

Private Sub btnRetrieve_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRetrieve.Click
    Try
        If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            RetrieveForm.Show()
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Try
        Retrieve()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub Retrieve()
    Try
        Dim thrd1 As New Thread(AddressOf RetrieveClient)
        Dim thrd2 As New Thread(AddressOf RetrieveProject)
        Dim thrd3 As New Thread(AddressOf RetrieveModule)
        Dim thrd4 As New Thread(AddressOf RetrievePerson)
        Dim thrd5 As New Thread(AddressOf RetrieveStatus)
        Dim thrd6 As New Thread(AddressOf RetrievePriority)

        thrd1.Start()
        thrd2.Start()
        thrd3.Start()
        thrd4.Start()
        thrd5.Start()
        thrd6.Start()

        thrd1.Join()
        thrd2.Join()
        thrd3.Join()
        thrd4.Join()
        thrd5.Join()
        thrd6.Join()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveClient()
    Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001)) ' 3 to 10 seconds of "work"

    ' ... code ...

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1)
End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveProject()
    Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001)) ' 3 to 10 seconds of "work"

    ' ... code ...

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(2)
End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveModule()
    Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001)) ' 3 to 10 seconds of "work"

    ' ... code ...

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(3)
End Sub

Private Sub RetrievePerson()
    Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001)) ' 3 to 10 seconds of "work"

    ' ... code ...

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(4)
End Sub

Private Sub RetrieveStatus()
    Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001)) ' 3 to 10 seconds of "work"

    ' ... code ...

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(5)
End Sub

Private Sub RetrievePriority()
    Thread.Sleep(R.Next(3000, 10001)) ' 3 to 10 seconds of "work"

    ' ... code ...

    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(6)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Select Case e.ProgressPercentage
        Case 1
            tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbClient)
        Case 2
            tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbProject)
        Case 3
            tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbModule)
        Case 4
            tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbUsers)
        Case 5
            tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbStatus)
        Case 6
            tickimage(RetrieveForm.pbPriority)
    End Select
End Sub

Public Sub tickimage(ByVal pbId As PictureBox)
    Try
        pbId.InitialImage = Nothing
        Dim img As Image = My.Resources.tick1
        pbId.Image = img
        pbId.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("Retrieved")
    RetrieveForm.Close()
    InitialLoad()
End Sub

Private Sub InitialLoad()
    Debug.Print("InitialLoad()")
End Sub
```

Comment: After buttton click, application freezes and shows message as "Application has stopped working, windows can check online for a solution to the problem and gives 3 options as "check online", "Close program" and "Debug Program"..

Comment: Well, the code I posted wouldn't cause that.  It must be something you're doing in one of the methods started in Threads by Retrieve().

Comment: Oh.., In all the methods, I retrieve xml from urls. Each method has different urls passing into it. Could you please tell how to extract xml from urls without causing the application to freeze...!!!
In retrieve form, no codes are written.

Comment: I just verified that the code doesn't cause any crashes.  You do, however, have to set the WorkerReportsProgress() property of the BackgroundWorker() control to True if you didn't already.

Comment: I'd start by commenting out all the Threading lines in Receive() just to see if the crash is being caused by something else.  Then you could uncomment the lines for just one thread at a time to troubleshoot.  Maybe you can narrow down the problem.

Comment: thrd3 is the problem. RetrieveModule() is extracting nearly 314 kB size of xml. All the images are changed to tick except 3rd(thrd3). Does that method need any separate thread to work properly...??

Comment: I'd say post another question specifically about the code in that thread.  The code I've posted is obviously working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some picture controls supports animated gifs, put an animated gif into the picture control.

if the control doesn't update as you wanted, maybe you need to add a timer and do a manual refresh of the control, with a `Application.DoEvents();` afterwards.